# How to custom a search filter in django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Model

```
class Student(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
        first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('first name'), max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
        last_name =models.CharField(verbose_name=_('last name'), max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
        
class Bicycle(models.Model):
            id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
            name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('bicycle name'), max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
            student_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4)
```

View:

```
class BicycleList(AdUpdateMixin, AdDestroyMixin, AdListMixin, AdCreateMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Bicycle.objects.all()
    search_fields = ['name', 'id', 'student_id']
```

Now, I want create a custom search field in django rest framework. So that I can search first_name and last_name in Bicycle List ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use student as a foreign key in Bicyle Model then you can query as:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Bicycle.objects.filter(
 Q(student__first_name__icontains=t)
 | Q(student__first_name__icontains=t)
 )
```

Comment: Thanks. If student field does not a foreinkey. Can I search it ?

Comment: It will be easier to use raw sql using join and then execute using cursor. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly